# Session not occuring when using condition on PHP

Tags: php, session, conditional-statements

I've been learning php language for a short time.Session not occuring when using condition but it works when out of condition.if($counter==1) condition is works.I can take response but only sessions didn't work.What's wrong?Sorry for my bad English.

```
 <?php 
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
try {

    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=raporlama;charset=utf8",'root','12345678');
    // echo "veritabanı bağlantısı başarılı";
  


}

catch (PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}

$action = $_POST['action'];
$response = [];
switch ($action) {
    case 'login':
      $user_mail = $_POST['user_mail'];
      $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];
      $data = [
          'user_mail' => $user_mail,
          'user_password' => $user_password
      ];
      $userQuery=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users where user_mail = :user_mail and user_password = :user_password");
      $userQuery->execute($data);
      echo $counter = $userQuery->rowCount();

      if($counter==1){
        $response = $user_mail;
        $_SESSION['user_mail'] = $user_mail;
        $_SESSION['isLoggedIn'] = true;
      } else{
          $response = "hata";
      }
        
      break;
      case 'isLoggedIn':
      if (isset($_SESSION['user_mail'])) {
        $response = $_SESSION['user_mail'];
      } else {
        $response = false;
      }
    break;
      }
          
    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Well presumably $counter did _not_ have the value `1` then ...

Comment: FYI, this `echo $counter = $userQuery->rowCount();` will break your functionality, if the receiver of this output expects JSON (which appears to be the case.)